# Swift - how to get the text to speech languages as descriptive string

Tags: swift, text-to-speech

I'm trying to get the text to speech language codes (in BCP 47) to transform into a descriptive string for selecting the language to have text to speech feature in the app.

Expected -

Arabic (Saudi Arabia) - ar-SA
Chinese (China) - zh-CN
Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China) - zh-HK
Chinese (Taiwan) - zh-TW
Czech (Czech Republic) - cs-CZ

Actual -

ar-SA (fixed)
cs-CZ (fixed)

```
class func getListOfSupportedLanguages() {
        for voice in (AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()){
            print(voice.language)
            let language = Locale.init(identifier: voice.language)
            print(language.description)
        }
    }
```

I'm following this helpful website and got different results.

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/synthesized-speech-from-text/

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *languageCodes;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *languageDictionary;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer;

- (NSArray *)languageCodes
{
    if (!_languageCodes)
    {
        _languageCodes = [self.languageDictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }
    return _languageCodes;
}

// Map between language codes and locale specific display name
- (NSDictionary *)languageDictionary
{
    if (!_languageDictionary)
    {
        NSArray *voices = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices];
        NSArray *languages = [voices valueForKey:@"language"];

        NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        for (NSString *code in languages)
        {
            dictionary[code] = [currentLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:code];
        }
        _languageDictionary = dictionary;
    }
    return _languageDictionary;
}
```

Comment: If the Objective C example gets the desired results, why don’t you do what it does?

Comment: I use swift like the question says. I tried to copy c objective over to swift, but I am getting different results. I am still not sure why it is happening.

Comment: But you didn’t translate the Objective C into Swift. You’re not doing what it does. So of course you get different results.

Comment: Let me double check the c objective code.

Comment: Or don’t translate it. A Swift project can have Objective C code in it.

Comment: I would prefer to understand the code and modify it to swift and probably will use it as a learning tool for speech to text languages as well.  Although, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: But clearly you don’t understand it. Your code is nothing like his. He calls https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1415931-displayname You never do. — If you want to get the same results as his code, then why don’t you do the same thing his code does?

Comment: Correct, that's why I'm here to ask questions. I used Locale.init(identifier) and thinking it was the correct one. I googled around and didn't see much information. I didn't think much between NSLocale and Locale.  I just learned that NSLocale and Locale have their own results. Thank you

Comment: Well if you don’t like NSLocale why don’t you try calling https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293396-localizedstring instead?

Comment: Not sure if that will work - localizedString(forRegionCode:). The values of languages from the voices are cs-CZ, da-DK, de-DE... it has language.. hypen... region code (IETF BCP 47 language tag). I'm cool with NSLocale.  I'm stepping over the debugger in the sample project and trying to understand why the NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]; is used. My C objective receptive skills are rusty.

Comment: If the problem is solved, please either delete the question or answer it yourself (perfectly legal). Do not include the answer in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, thanks to Matt - NSLocale has displayName and the Locale doesn't have one. According to the posting below

NSLocale Swift 3

Here is the code -

```
   class func getListOfSupportedLanguages() {
         let current = Locale.current.languageCode

         for voice in (AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()){
              let language = NSLocale.init(localeIdentifier: current!)
              print(language.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.identifier, value: voice.language)?.description as! String)
         }
   }
```

the output -

```
English (Australia)
English (United Kingdom)
English (Ireland)
English (United States)
English (South Africa)
```

Comment: you need use Locale method `localizedString(forLanguageCode` and use English locale `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX").localizedString(forLanguageCode: "en")`  // "English"

Comment: If you want that language in Portuguese `Locale(identifier: "pt_BR").localizedString(forLanguageCode: "en")`  // "inglês"

Comment: and for the timezone identifier as well `Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX").localizedString(forIdentifier: "en_US") `

Comment: That doesn't work well - 

language.displayName
English (Australia)
English (United Kingdom)
English (Ireland)
English (United States)
English (South Africa)

.localizedString values
English
English
English
English
English

Comment: Just use `en` to get English only

Comment: Sorry if you don’t show the input and expected output it is hard to understand what you need

Comment: yes, there are output values in comment but it doesn't look good. getting NSLocale.displayNames is what I needed.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. Usually you should be able  to solve your issue with just Locale (Swift native type)

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is Make sure to import the `AVFoundation` library into the header (.h) file that will implement the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` or `AVSpeechSynthesizer` along with its properties and methods are not accessible.

Ex: `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Great feedback in this post. Thanks everyone.